# SVN- overwrite a specific file from SVN

Tags: svn, svn-update

I use `svn` on Linux.
I did `svn update` succesfully.
After I did the update I wanted to see the status so I did `svn status`.
I can see that I have 3 files with `M` (e.g `M       sarit/src/main.cpp`).
How can I force those files to update/overwrite?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I force those files to update/overwrite?

**Update** and **overwrite** mean different things. On `svn update`, each file is updated. This means each file contains the latest changes committed to the repository by other developers since the last time you updated it **and** the changes you did on it since the last time you committed it (if there are any changes).

`svn status` reports these files as **M**odified. This means you have changes not committed on this files.

If you want to overwrite the local copies of your files with the versions received from the repository then your local changes will be lost.

If you are sure this is what you want (discard your changes) then you can revert these files to the content they had when you last time updated them.

The command is `svn revert`. Run `svn help revert` to get more info about it.

**Update:**

As user @bahrep suggests, it's better to read the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) first. It explains the key concepts of a versioning system and how they are implemented in Subversion. It also explains the `svn` commands, with examples. The help you get using `svn help <command>` is useful when you know how to use `svn` and what's the expected outcome of each command and you only need a quick recall of the arguments needed by a specific command.

A quick tour on using Subversion can be found on the [Basic Work Cycle](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html) page.

Comment: I'd better refer to SVNBook instead of `svn help foo`: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve.revert & http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html